# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'method' and 'method'

Tags: python, typeerror, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I was going to try and make a turtle race that makes you pick a turtle name and try to be able to guess the turtle that will win the race i have had a few issues so far but right now i cannot figrure out what went wrong so can someone tell me why this error code appeared? (i am new to stack overflow)

```
import turtle
import random
from turtle import *
from random import randint
speed()
penup()
goto(-140, 140)

for i in range(15):
  write(i,align = "center")
  right(90)

  for num in range(8):
    penup()
    forward(10)
    pendown()
    forward(10)

  penup()
  backward(160)
  left(90)
  forward(20)
A = turtle.Turtle()
A.shape('turtle')
A.color('red')
A.penup()
A.goto(-160, 100)

B = turtle.Turtle()
B.shape('turtle')
B.color('red')
B.penup()
B.goto(-160, 70)

C = turtle.Turtle()
C.shape('turtle')
C.color('red')
C.penup()
C.goto(-160, 40)
random.randint(1, 5)
random = random.randint(1, 7)
  
D = turtle.Turtle()
D.shape('turtle')
D.color('red')
D.penup()
D.goto(-160, 10)
for i in range(100):
  A.forward(randint(1,5))
  B.forward(randint(1,5))
  C.forward(randint(1,5))
  D.forward(randint(1,5))
if A.xcor > B.xcor and A.xcor > C.xcor and A.xcor > D.xcor:
  print("Wow the turtle you picked you picked wow the race!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xcor` attribute of a `turtle.Turtle` object is not a simple attribute, but a *method* defined by the class. The code should compare the *values that are returned* from that method; therefore, the code should *call* the method (using `()`) to get that value.

Change:

```
if A.xcor > B.xcor and A.xcor > C.xcor and A.xcor > D.xcor():
  print("Wow the turtle you picked you picked wow the race!")
```

to:

```
if A.xcor() > B.xcor() and A.xcor() > C.xcor() and A.xcor() > D.xcor():
    print("Wow the turtle you picked you picked wow the race!")
```

This can be simplified using the built-in [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function:

```
if all(A.xcor() > t.xcor() for t in [B, C, D]):
    print("Wow the turtle you picked you picked wow the race!")
```

Comment: The `xcor` attribute of a `Turtle` object is not a *class* function but an *instance* method.

Comment: @cdlane Is there such thing as a class function then?

Comment: @AnnZen That would be known as a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).

Answer (score 1):

@RandomDavis covers your primary error in their comment (+1), but there are other issues.  E.g. `speed()` and `random.randint(1, 5)` by themselves are no-ops.  Also, you're in trouble when you have to import both turtle and random two different ways.  Let's rework your code into a valid program:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

screen = Screen()

marker = Turtle()
marker.speed('fastest')
marker.penup()
marker.goto(-140, 140)

for number in range(15):
    marker.write(number, align="center")
    marker.right(90)

    for _ in range(8):
        marker.penup()
        marker.forward(10)
        marker.pendown()
        marker.forward(10)

    marker.penup()
    marker.backward(160)
    marker.left(90)
    marker.forward(20)

marker.hideturtle()

A = Turtle()
A.shape('turtle')
A.color('red')
A.penup()
A.goto(-160, 100)

B = Turtle()
B.shape('turtle')
B.color('red')
B.penup()
B.goto(-160, 70)

C = Turtle()
C.shape('turtle')
C.color('red')
C.penup()
C.goto(-160, 40)

D = Turtle()
D.shape('turtle')
D.color('red')
D.penup()
D.goto(-160, 10)

for _ in range(100):
    A.forward(randint(1, 5))
    B.forward(randint(1, 5))
    C.forward(randint(1, 5))
    D.forward(randint(1, 5))

if A.xcor() > B.xcor() and A.xcor() > C.xcor() and A.xcor() > D.xcor():
    print("The turtle you picked you picked won the race!")

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]